# BlueImp Gallery - How to deactivate swipe event

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I am using [BlueImp Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) ([DEMO](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/)). I need to lock hide the buttons on certain situations, that worked great. But now I also need to hide the mouse and touch swipes as well.

**Explanation**: Users can swipe left or right, this will change the current picture.

I was not able to find the responsible event yet. How can I deactivate the swipe events and active it again? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(document).on('click touchmove',function(){
   if(CERTAIN_SITUATIONS){ // only on certain situations
       return false;// it will prevent to do anything in your document
   }
});
```

If you want a div or container to be disable then use it like,

```
$(document).on('click touchmove','CONTAINER_ID_OR_CLASS',function(){
   ....
```

You can use [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation) to prevent bubbling,

```
$(document).on('click touchmove',function(e){
   if(CERTAIN_SITUATIONS){ // only on certain situations
       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;// it will prevent to do anything in your document
   }
});
```

Comment: I think I will have to create a workaround to prevent the swipe. I will place a transparent div over the galerie to catch all mouse clicks, swipes etc....

Comment: What does `bubbling` mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

They had no intend of publishing this feature, but it's in there.

```
var galleryContext

// initalize your gallery
blueimp.Gallery([{/* your images */}], {

  // we need the context of the gallery
  onopened: function () {
    galleryContext = this
  }

})

// now disable 
galleryContext.destroyEventListeners()

// or enable
galleryContext.initEventListeners()
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: (tested on v3.2.0)

```
this.galleryInstance = blueimp(this.config.images, options);
this.galleryInstance.destroyEventListeners();
//this line makes sure no touch events are registered in the init function
//and preserving other events in tact
this.galleryInstance.support.touch = false;
this.galleryInstance.initEventListeners();
```